# Does HTML5 Web Storage API still work offline?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, web-storage

By Web Storage I am referring to: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

Since Web Storage is client-side, will it still work without a current internet connection?
Provided all scripts etc. were already loaded, if the user then lost connection or set their browser to offline mode, would any web storage processing still work? (e.g. getting and setting keys in local/session storage)

Comment: I know what it is... that wasn't the question

Comment: i didn't have patience to read complete question...your question is invalid that's not possible.

Comment: @susheel How can a question be "invalid"? Why isn't it possible?

Comment: so you are expecting cache to do your work ?

Comment: @bjb568 I think he meant that was his answer.. as in, "it's not possile for web storage to work offline"

Comment: yes you are right @MaggGray  i meant that

Comment: @susheel Ok, could you make your claim into an answer?

Comment: you need to use HTML5 application cache http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp

Comment: @susheel ah, I'm not talking about downloading any more data/web pages whilst offline - part of the condition in my question was that all resources were already loaded

Comment: @MaggGray loaded in the sense you are not gonna refresh the page ? in that case it would work perfectly.

Comment: @susheel yes, that's what I was asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. To get and set local storage, session storage, or cookies, the computer must be connected… to itself. That doesn't require an internet connection.

So if the everything you need is downloaded (like in cache), you have everything you need. Everything is on the computer.